# What is the proper way to shutdown linux and then kill power?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, shutdown

I am running Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ on a raspberrypi board with an external power supply. The power supply "off" switch is controlled via the GPIO's.

I'd like to do a "shutdown -h -P now", wait for the system to shutdown (halt), then kill the power by running a program (killpower) to toggle the appropriate gpio pin.  My main goal is to ensure that the file system is in a state where it won't get corrupted when the power is removed.

I've tried to take advantage of the runlevel 1 script killproc that sends SIGTERM (and SIGKILL) to every running process.  I wrote killpower to catch SIGTERM, wait 20 seconds, then send the gpio powerkill sequence. I also modified the killproc script to NOT SIGKILL my killpower pid even if it is still running after the SIGTERM timeout.

When this did not work, I discovered that after killproc runs, the /init.d/halt SCRIPT runs, which calls /sbin/halt.  /sbin/halt also kills all processes with SIGKILL, so I expect my killpower proc got killed before the 20 seconds was up.  Now, I don't see how this approach is going to work.

I also see that init can act on a SIGPWR signal (not recommended) but it can execute powerwait/powerfail.  Is the system in a state to power off at this point?  I can't seem to find out what these programs are supposed to implement.

I thought about installing another shutdown script in init.d but I'm confused about what run level it should "stop" at (level 1 or level 0).

Is it OK to kill power just before the /sbin/halt is executed as a result of the shutdown command?  Am I correct that once /sbin/halt is executed, nothing else will ever run?

Comment: If you are concerned about corrupting your file system, how about trying to remount the fs with `ro` (readonly) option after all other processes that might keep files open for writing have been killed (e.g. rsyslogd). If remounting read-only succeeded, it should be safe to kill the power without corrupting anything. Not sure whether remounting flushes the cashes, so maybe add a call to `sync`.

Comment: looking at the /etc/rc0.d scripts, there is umountfs and umountroot which do exactly that: remount the fs ro.  I've put my "killpower" proc to execute just after that, but before halt. I think the real solution may be to rebuild the kernel with ACPI in it, but that may be on another day.

Answer (score 0):

The way I power off a linux box when I am logged into it remotely is to simply use the 'poweroff' command. The system then shuts down properly and finally turns itself off--nothing more, nothing less, exactly what I want.

Comment: poweroff is the same as halt -p.  If halt is called when not at run level 0, it calls shutdown. shutdown eventually takes the system to runlevel 0, and then halt is called.  I need a hook into halt to actually command the power supply to turn off.